# select only certain classes in html file using getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a large html file converted from a .doc file that I am trying to parse info out of and put into a database.  The html document consists of headers which are all

I am trying to do this via DOMDocument, however I am open to try another method.

I have found that I cannot use `$dom->getElementsByTagName('span class="c1 c4"')`, is there a way to use this function to select specific classes?

Comment: Not with that method - all it does is get elements by tag name, not class name.

Answer (score 6):

gEBTN() only retrieves tag names. You'll have to loop over the returned list of elements and test each element's classes:

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $classes = $node->getAttribute('class');
    ... test for your css classes ...
}
```

However, using XPath, this is much easier:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xp->query('//span[@class="c1 c4"]');
```